# Uipath: Robot status is always disconnected

Tags: rpa, uipath

I installed Uipath Studio Enterprise Trial Edition 2018 on a Windows 10 home machine and I am trying to connect a robot to orchestrator community edition (2018) but my robot status is always disconnected in orchestrator

I did the following steps as described in the documentation:

1. Added a machine in the machines section and retrieved the machine key
2. Added a standard robot in the robots section (I double checked my credentials and there is no mistake)
3. Run UipathRobot.exe and checked its status in windows services.
4. Changed the settings of the Uipath robot and clicked connect.
5. The robot status shows licensed, connected on my machine but shows disconnected on orchestrator

The screenshots below show the robot status on my machine and on orchestrator.

[image: Robot status on my machine]

[image: Robot status in orchestrator]

If you had a similar issue before, please assist.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure robots are having proper domain/username and password, generally you can get it by running whoami in cmd.

Complete result you can paste under domain/username section then in password field you paste just username(generally username and passwords are same)

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure the name that is defined in the uirobot / botagent is the same as that made as the name of the machine in the orchestrator
- Make sure the URL Orchestrator is http://platform.uipath.com/[AccountLogicalName]/[ServiceName]/.
  example: https://platform.uipath.com/ptxyz/xyz/
- Make sure the Machine key in the uirobot is the same as that of the machine key used in the orchestrator
- Make sure the robot domain is correct by searching on the console and using whoami
- Make sure the creating sequence in orchestrator = 1.create machine, 2. create robot, 3. create environment

Answer (score 1):

Please open a CMD in your robot machine and type “whoami”.
The result should be the input you need to add in your domain\username field when provisioning a robot.

If you are using a domain user you need to put domain\username.
If it’s a local user you need to add machineName\username.

Answer (score 1):

Add the processes for the environments. After adding this should be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

All the steps are correct except the URL, UI Path documents suggest the Orchestrator URL as follows

```
http://platform.uipath.com/[AccountLogicalName]/[ServiceName]
```

[Here](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/docs/connecting-robots-to-orchestrator#section-from-orchestrator-and-the-orchestrator-settings-window) is the complete step by step guide.

Answer (score 1):

Let me just repeat the scenario, because if I understand it correctly, there is only one possible reason for the robot show as disconnected when trying to run a robot.

- The machine has been successfully created in UiPath Orchestrator
- The URL and Machine Key have been entered correctly in [UiPath Assistant](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-configure-Assistant-and-publish-to-UiPath-Orchestrator)
- UiPath Assistant shows a green status with the words 'Connected' and 'licensed'
- The robot or machine status is disconnected in [UiPath Orchestrator](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-create-a-UiPath-Orchestrator-process-to-run-your-RPA-robots)

### Hostname vs. Machine Name

The only explanation for this is the machine name entered in UiPath Orchestrator is not the same as the hostname of the machine on which the robot runs. In the Command Prompt, both the whoami and hostname commands will show you the name you should use for the machine.

Update this field in the Machines section under the Management section of the admin console, reconnect from [UiPath](http://uipath.rpacertified.com/study-guide-uipath.html) Assistant and your machine status should change to connected.

The following image shows an instance where the machine will show as disconnected, even if UiPath Assistant connects. Notice how the hostname and the machine name are not the same. This is most likely the issue.

[image: hostname and machine name mapping]